# How to provision access to ECR for IAM user in ElasticBeanstalk Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I have elastic beanstalk template as following. I am using multi-container docker. So I pushed my image to ECR separately. In `Dockerrun.json`, I referred to my image like this `"image": "*****.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/******:latest"`. By using this CF template I am able to create ELB with multi container. But while deploying my `Dockerrun.json`, It failed due to permission denied for my image. So I added `Type: AWS::ECR::Repository` to my cloud formation.I already have `MyInstanceProfile` in my CF. Here I want to add ECR permission to `MyInstanceProfile`. So how assign the ECR permission to ElasticbeanStalk cloud formation template?.

````
Resources:
  sampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application
  sampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: !Sub "elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-182107200133"
        S3Key: TravelTouch/Dockerrun.aws.json
  MyRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: "test-repository"
      RepositoryPolicyText:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowPushPull
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
               /*
                Here how to assign permission to MyInstanceProfile
               */
            Action:
              - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
              - "ecr:BatchGetImage"
              - "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
              - "ecr:PutImage"
              - "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload"
              - "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
              - "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
  sampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: '2'
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize
          Value: '6'
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: LoadBalanced
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value: !Ref MyInstanceProfile
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.26.0 running Multi-container Docker 19.03.13-ce (Generic)
  sampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment
      TemplateName:
        Ref: sampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: sampleApplicationVersion
  MyInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Description: Beanstalk EC2 role
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
  MyInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref MyInstanceRole```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would specify **ARN of the role**:

```
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt MyInstanceRole.Arn
```

Update:

```
  MyInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Description: Beanstalk EC2 role
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AllowGetAuthorizationToken
          PolicyDocument: |
            {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                      "Sid": "ECSAccess",
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Action": [
                          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                      ],
                      "Resource": "*"
                  }
              ]
          }
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I am getting ```Resource handler returned message: "Invalid parameter at 'PolicyText' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid repository policy provided' (Service: Ecr, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 62b7161d-a133-4791-9cb3-0392431e0eb1, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 155b2c33-f126-f4a2-4a87-e1ae90668862, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)```  this error while creating stack

Comment: is anything need to add in MyInstanceRole `Principal: Service:` section regarding ECR?

Comment: @NatheeshkumarRangasamy You shoudn't need `RepositoryPolicyText` at all as you already have intane role with ecr policy

Comment: ok @Marcin, Now while running `Dockerrun.json` , I am getting `ECS task stopped due to: Task failed to start. (web: CannotPullECRContainerError: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::182107200133:assumed-role/SIVVVAMMM-MyInstanceRole-TRQKYWE4PVO6/i-00343ad943a37d429 is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * status code: 400, request id db: )` error. so how we provision the read access to my image?

Comment: @NatheeshkumarRangasamy You can add it, as in the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I am getting `Encountered unsupported property MyInstanceRole` while creating stack. Is any valid properties Marcin..?

Comment: @NatheeshkumarRangasamy The code seem correct unless you modified it. You can make new question with new code if you have any changes in it.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I created another question as you said. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213063/how-to-provision-ecr-read-access-to-elastic-beanstalk-cloudformation-template Please take a look.

Comment: Definitely @Marcin. That's true.