# Getting Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument for while creating Cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create cloud formation template for ECR and ELB, I pushed my image to ECR separately. In Dockerrun.json, I referred to my image like this "image": ".dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/*:latest". So I need to provide IAM permission for both ELB and ECR. But there is some issue with IAM part in this template. Getting this error while creating the stack. Is any fixes is required?

```
Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 8b9b3f05-51c9-41e1-b008-c59aa319c086; Proxy: null)
```

```
Resources:
  sampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application
  sampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: !Sub "elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-1-182107200133"
        S3Key: TravelTouch/Dockerrun.aws.json
  MyRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: "182107200133.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/socialbox"
  sampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: '2'
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize
          Value: '6'
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: LoadBalanced
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value: !Ref MyInstanceProfile
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.26.0 running Multi-container Docker 19.03.13-ce (Generic)

  sampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment
      TemplateName:
        Ref: sampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: sampleApplicationVersion

  MyInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Description: Beanstalk EC2 role
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AllowGetAuthorizationToken
          PolicyDocument: |
            {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                      "Sid": "ECSAccess",
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Action": [
                          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                      ],
                      "Resource": "*"
                  }
              ]
            }  

  MyInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref MyInstanceRole
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `,` in the wrong place. Instead of:

```
"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
```

it should be (no comma):

```
"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
```